# Group by column and assign value to a new column based on other column values in python

Tags: python, group-by

I have following dataframe

```
col1        col2            col3
HP:0002616  ['HP:0001679']  Abnormal aortic morphology
HP:0002616  ['HP:0002597']  Abnormality of the vasculature
HP:0002616  ['HP:0001626']  Abnormality of the cardiovascular system
HP:0002616  ['HP:0000118']  Phenotypic abnormality
HP:0002616  ['HP:0000118']  disease
HP:0002616  ['HP:0000118']  quality
HP:0002616  ['HP:0000118']  material property
HP:0002616  ['HP:0000118']  experimental factor
HP:0002616  ['HP:0000118']  Thing
HP:0002616  ['HP:0030680']  Abnormality of cardiovascular system morphology
HP:0002616  ['HP:0002617']  Vascular dilatation 
HP:0010689  ['HP:0011297']  Abnormal digit morphology   
HP:0010689  ['HP:0011842']  Abnormal skeletal morphology    
HP:0010689  ['HP:0000924']  Abnormality of the skeletal system  
HP:0010689  ['HP:0000118']  Phenotypic abnormality  
HP:0010689  ['HP:0000118']  phenotype
```

The expected output is:

```
col1        col4           
HP:0002616  disease 
HP:0010689  phenotype
```

I would like to create a new column based on values in col3 group by col1. For a col1 value, if col3 has 'disease', a new column col4 will have value 'disease',   if col3 has 'phenotpye', a new column col4 will have value 'phenotype'. If both value exists, then col4 will have disease, phenotype. How can I achieve this?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: what exactly have you tried so far that _didn't work_? a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would go a long way towards this

Comment: Is the dataframe a huge string?

Comment: try: `df.query("col3 in ['disease', 'phenotype']").groupby('col1')['col3'].agg(','.join)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filter the records for the needed keywords with [`Series.str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html), then - group and join:

```
(df.loc[df['col3'].str.contains(r'disease|phenotype')]
 .groupby('col1')['col3'].agg(','.join).reset_index(name='col4'))
```

---

```
         col1       col4
0  HP:0002616    disease
1  HP:0010689  phenotype
```